# Linq - check from list some thing like in used in to query on set in SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
 List<Guid?> MobileAppID = new List<Guid?>();

return  d
.Where(x => x.MarketplaceID IN MobileAppID)
.ToList();
```

I want to select values from the d where MarketplaceID  in MobileAppID.MobileAppID is a set 
How would i do that in LINQ C#. Something like select in query in SQL Server

d is a class containing  MarketplaceID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent would be a `Contains` query:

```
return  d
.Where(x => MobileAppID.Contains(x.MarketplaceID))
.ToList();
```

Might want to make `MobileAppID` a `HashSet` to speed this up.

Comment: good solution, if you are looking for more detailed solution just visit http://www.dotnetspan.com/2014/10/use-where-in-clause-in-linq-and-entity-framework.html